# Syntax Error in mysqli_query

Tags: php

```
$db_query = mysqli_query($link, "Select Name,  BriefDescription, SUM(Runs) as Runs
                                FROM BaseTable
                                WHERE  RunDate >= DATE_ADD(day, -$dataRange, getdate() ) AND RunDate <= getdate() 
                                GROUP BY Name,  BreifDescription");
```

The error message I am getting is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-30, getdate() ) AND RunDate <= getdate() GROU' at line 3
```

and I am confused as to where my error is

Comment: WHERE  RunDate >= DATE_ADD(day, -$dataRange, getdate() ) You have an extra parenthesis

Comment: _expr_ is a **string**; it may start with a - for negative intervals. Need to quote strings.

Comment: It needs `INTERVAL X UNIT`, not just a number. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 0):

```
$db_query = mysqli_query($link, "Select Name,  BriefDescription, SUM(Runs) as Runs
                                FROM BaseTable
                                WHERE  RunDate >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $dataRange day) AND RunDate <= CURDATE()
                                GROUP BY Name,  BreifDescription");
```

Changing to use CURDATE() and interval seemed to work around this issue.

Answer (score -1):

DATE_ADD only takes 2 parameters, you have 3.

date_add(day, offset)